# Git Command Does not Work in Windows CMD

Tags: windows, git, bash, cmd

I am trying the below command in Windows CMD for Bitnami Gitlab VM machine at Windows 10.

```
git clone git@192.168.1.10:user/project.git
```

It works in Git Bash but the same command does not work for Windows CMD.

I suspect when used in Windows CMD ssh is looking for wrong keys and the output is:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

The command works in Git Bash terminal but I like to use Windows CMD.

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect when used in Windows CMD ssh is looking for wrong key

You don't have to suspect. You can see it.

Check that:

- your `PATH` does reference `<git>/usr/bin`
- where ssh is indeed `ssh.exe` from `<git>/usr/bin`
- `HOME` is set to the parent folder of your `.ssh` is

Then type:

```
ssh -Tv git@192.168.1.10
```

If the wrong ssh key is used, defines it in a [`.ssh/config` file](https://serverfault.com/a/498281/783).

```
Host mygitserver
   Hostname 192.168.1.10
   User git
   IdentityFile "/C/path/to/my/private/key"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `HOME` so that the CMD will be able to find your ssh keys under the `.ssh` folder

```
set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not help. Still getting "Permission denied (publickey)"

Comment: Ok try to restart the ssh agent by typing this in our git bash and than try to connect : **eval \`ssh-agent\`**